# How to connect the docusign with aws s3 cloud?

Tags: docusignapi

I want to access documents from our s3 bucket and upload to docusign for sign from recipients , and after the sign completion the document need to upload again to our s3 bucket.

How can this possible with docusign i want to know the process for it .It is is possible with rest api also let me know .

Please give me the solution for it .Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS provides SDK for many of the programming language (C#, Java, Python..) you can use SDK to download(GetObject the PDF and make DocuSign API call to send it for Signature. And once Signing sessions completes get the completed document using DocuSign API and upload to bucekts using AWS s3 API's.

---To Download From S3----
aws s3api get-object --bucket "YOURBUCKETNAME" --key "INPUT.PDF" "OUT.PDF"

====DocuSign API===

---To Upload to S3----
aws s3api put-object --bucket "YOURBUCKETNAME" --key "SIGNED.PDF" --body c:\SIGNED.PDDF

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you have any document for this workflow. If you have please send it to me.